# Who are the Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Before getting strange, please read the question. :)

I just watched the movie, twice, and they talk about someone being a guardian of the galaxy on a couple of occasions. And around the end of the movie Quill says something like: "we are the guardians of the Galaxy".

But it seems that nowhere in the movie is it explained who those Guardians are, if they are a real association or if it is just a name they give themselves during the movie or if it is just a teaser developed during the movie.

They are clearly not part of any association and when they leave together at the end of the movie, they are just friends leaving together.

So my question is, in the MCU at the moment the movie takes place, is there something called Guardians of the Galaxy that is recognized and/or known?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Through the course of the movie, there is no officially recognized group called "The Guardians of the Galaxy".

The ragtag group of convicts band together for similar purposes, but do not have a collective name or official membership.

Ronan is actually the first one to label them with a name other than "losers" or "a bunch of a-holes".

> Ronan: Behold!  Your Guardians of the Galaxy!

Peter and the group later assume the sarcastic name as their own.

> Peter: You said it yourself, bitch… we’re the Guardians of the Galaxy.

It can be noted that the trailer shows Corpsman Dey saying that they call themselves "The Guardians of the Galaxy", but the bit of dialogue was used only for the trailer.

Comment: on that line "other than 'losers'" you should add "or a-holes."

Comment: @Omegacron I couldn't remember if that ended up in the final movie or not.

Comment: Yep, just watched it night before last. The line "They call themselves the 'Guardians of the Galaxy' wasn't there during the lineup scene, but the 'What a bunch of a-holes.' line definitely was. IIRC when Quill contacted Dey to warn him about Ronan coming, he also referred to himself as an "a-hole" so Dey would know who he was.

Comment: @Omegacron Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: In the comics, the Guardians of the Galaxy do coalesce into a recognized group, but they don't gain much notoriety outside of the planet (Knowhere) where they set up camp.